# Merge two (or more) lists into one, in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, list

Is it possible to convert two or more lists into one single list, in .NET using C#?

For example,

```
public static List<Product> GetAllProducts(int categoryId){ .... }
.
.
.
var productCollection1 = GetAllProducts(CategoryId1);
var productCollection2 = GetAllProducts(CategoryId2);
var productCollection3 = GetAllProducts(CategoryId3);
```

Comment: Do you want to merge productCollection1 2 and 3?

Comment: do you mean merge more than one list in one list ?

Comment: Your example is confusing me...are you looking for the `AddRange`-Method?

Comment: LINQ is overkill. [AddRange()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=netcore-3.1) is the way to go!

Answer (score 622, accepted):

You can use the LINQ [`Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) and [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) methods:

```
var allProducts = productCollection1.Concat(productCollection2)
                                    .Concat(productCollection3)
                                    .ToList();
```

Note that there are more efficient ways to do this - the above will basically loop through all the entries, creating a dynamically sized buffer. As you can predict the size to start with, you don't need this dynamic sizing... so you *could* use:

```
var allProducts = new List<Product>(productCollection1.Count +
                                    productCollection2.Count +
                                    productCollection3.Count);
allProducts.AddRange(productCollection1);
allProducts.AddRange(productCollection2);
allProducts.AddRange(productCollection3);
```

(`AddRange` is special-cased for `ICollection<T>` for efficiency.)

I wouldn't take this approach unless you really have to though.

Comment: BTW, `productCollection1.ForEach(p => allProducts.Add(p))` is more performant than AddRange.

Comment: @MarcCliment: That's a fairly bold blanket statement - especially as `AddRange` gets to do a block copy from one underlying array to another. Do you have any links for evidence of this?

Comment: @JonSkeet For the particular case of adding two lists, I've written this https://gist.github.com/4690433 and consistently List.ForEach is faster. Maybe the test is wrong...

Comment: @MarcCliment: Well for one thing, in your tests you're *not* creating the list with the correct final size - whereas the code in my answer does. Do that, and the 10000*10000 test is faster using AddRange, at least - although other results are inconsistent. (You should also force garbage collection between tests - and I'd argue that the very short tests are meaninglessly small.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for your suggestions. I updated the Gist but ForEach slightly outperforms AddRange in this particular case.

Comment: @MarcCliment: Which particular case? Which CLR? Which CPU architecture? On my machine I get a mixture of results. This is why I'm loathe to state/accept blanket statements such as "BTW, `productionCollection1.ForEach(...)` is more performant than AddRange". Performance is very rarely so easily described. I *am* surprised that AddRange isn't beating it handily though - I need to investigate that further.

Comment: I have something like this: `var allProducts = lstName.Concat(lstCMSID)
         .Concat(lstSpecialtyPhys)
         .ToList();` which adds it to the GridView but as one column. I would like to split them into three separate columns.

Comment: I've updated the gist (https://gist.github.com/mcliment/4690433) with the performance test using BenchmarksDotNet and properly tested, `AddRange` is the best option for raw speed (about 4x and the larger the lists the better the increase), as Jon suggeste.

Answer (score 62):

Assuming you want a list containing *all* of the products for the specified category-Ids, you can treat your query as a *projection* followed by a *flattening* operation. There's a LINQ operator that does that: [**`SelectMany`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx).

```
// implicitly List<Product>
var products = new[] { CategoryId1, CategoryId2, CategoryId3 }
                     .SelectMany(id => GetAllProducts(id))
                     .ToList();
```

In C# 4, you can shorten the SelectMany to: `.SelectMany(GetAllProducts)`

If you already have lists representing the products for each Id, then what you need is a *concatenation*, as others point out.

Comment: If the OP doesn't need the individual lists for any other reason, this is a great solution.

Comment: Having a similar problem and was about to give up and post a question, when I found this.  This is the best answer.  Especially if the code already has those categories in a list or array, which was true in my case.

Answer (score 38):

you can combine them using LINQ:

```
  list = list1.Concat(list2).Concat(list3).ToList();
```

the more traditional approach of using `List.AddRange()` might be more efficient though.

Comment: There are various flavors of merging here ==> https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/58779028.html

Answer (score 23):

[List.AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) will change (mutate) an existing list by adding additional elements:

```
list1.AddRange(list2); // list1 now also has list2's items appended to it.
```

Alternatively, in modern immutable style, you can project out a new list without changing the existing lists:

[Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat), which presents an unordered sequence of `list1`'s items, followed by `list2`'s items:

```
var concatenated = list1.Concat(list2).ToList();
```

Not quite the same, [Union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat) projects a distinct sequence of items:

```
var distinct = list1.Union(list2).ToList();
```

Note that for the 'value type distinct' behaviour of `Union` to work on reference types, that you will need to [define equality comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13417654/314291) for your classes (or alternatively use the built in comparators of `record` types).

Answer (score 12):

You could use the [Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) extension method:

```
var result = productCollection1
    .Concat(productCollection2)
    .Concat(productCollection3)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 12):

I know this is an old question I thought I might just add my 2 cents.

If you have a `List<Something>[]` you can join them using `Aggregate`

```
public List<TType> Concat<TType>(params List<TType>[] lists)
{
    var result = lists.Aggregate(new List<TType>(), (x, y) => x.Concat(y).ToList());

    return result;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Finally a useful answer that doesn't assume you have your objects ready and labeled at compile time.

Comment: @Daniel: I want to understand your remark but I don't. Can you help me and elaborate? Thx for the help!

Comment: @qqtf instead of `list1.Concat(list2).Concat(list3)`
what if you had a variable amount of lists ? or a List<List<T>>

Answer (score 10):

```
list4 = list1.Concat(list2).Concat(list3).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
// I would make it a little bit more simple

 var products = new List<List<product>> {item1, item2, item3 }.SelectMany(id => id).ToList();
```

This way it is a multi dimensional List and the .SelectMany() will flatten it into a IEnumerable of product then I use the .ToList() method after.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from C# 12 you may use the [Collection Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-12#collection-expressions) and *spread operator* `..`, for example:

```
List<Product> productCollection1 = GetAllProducts(CategoryId1);
List<Product> productCollection2 = GetAllProducts(CategoryId2);

List<Product> allProducts = [..productCollection1, ..productCollection2];
```

**Note:** The feature is part of [.NET 8](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/8.0) released in Nov 2023.

Answer (score 2):

I've already commented it but I still think is a valid option, just test if in your environment is better one solution or the other. In my particular case, using `source.ForEach(p => dest.Add(p))` performs better than the classic `AddRange` but I've not investigated why at the low level.

You can see an example code here: https://gist.github.com/mcliment/4690433

So the option would be:

```
var allProducts = new List<Product>(productCollection1.Count +
                                    productCollection2.Count +
                                    productCollection3.Count);

productCollection1.ForEach(p => allProducts.Add(p));
productCollection2.ForEach(p => allProducts.Add(p));
productCollection3.ForEach(p => allProducts.Add(p));
```

Test it to see if it works for you.

**Disclaimer**: I'm not advocating for this solution, I find `Concat` the most clear one. I just stated -in my discussion with Jon- that in my machine this case performs better than `AddRange`, but he says, with far more knowledge than I, that this does not make sense. There's the gist if you want to compare.

Comment: Regardless of your debate with Jon Skeet in the comments, I much prefer the cleanness offered by his proposed solution, this just adds unnecessary interpretation as to the intention of the code.

Comment: I think the most clear option is Concat as a generalization of AddRange, semantically more correct and does not modify the list in-place which makes it chainable. The discussion with Jon was about performance, not cleanliness.

Comment: I have something like this: `var allProducts = lstName.Concat(lstCMSID)
         .Concat(lstSpecialtyPhys)
         .ToList();` which adds it to the GridView but as one column. I would like to split them into three separate columns.

Answer (score 2):

To merge or Combine to Lists into a One list.

- There is one thing that must be true: the type of both list will be
  equal.
- **For Example**: if we have list of `string` so we can add add another list to the
  existing list which have list of type string otherwise we can't.

**Example**:

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      List<string> CustomerList_One = new List<string> 
      {
         "James",
         "Scott",
         "Mark",
         "John",
         "Sara",
         "Mary",
         "William",
         "Broad",
         "Ben",
         "Rich",
         "Hack",
         "Bob"
      };

      List<string> CustomerList_Two = new List<string> 
      {
         "Perter",
         "Parker",
         "Bond",
         "been",
         "Bilbo",
         "Cooper"
      };

      // Adding all contents of CustomerList_Two to CustomerList_One.
      CustomerList_One.AddRange(CustomerList_Two);

      // Creating another Listlist and assigning all Contents of CustomerList_One.
      List<string> AllCustomers = new List<string>();

      foreach (var item in CustomerList_One)
      {
         AllCustomers.Add(item);
      }

      // Removing CustomerList_One & CustomerList_Two.
      CustomerList_One = null;

      CustomerList_Two = null;
      // CustomerList_One & CustomerList_Two -- (Garbage Collected)
      GC.Collect();

      Console.WriteLine("Total No. of Customers : " +  AllCustomers.Count());
      Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------");
      foreach (var customer in AllCustomers)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Customer : " + customer);
      }
      Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------");

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*In the special case: "All elements of List1 goes to a new List2": (e.g. a string list)*

```
List<string> list2 = new List<string>(list1);
```

In this case, *list2* is generated with all elements from list1.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use Concat operation

Answer (score -1):

When you got few list but you don't know how many exactly, use this:

`listsOfProducts` contains few lists filled with objects.

```
List<Product> productListMerged = new List<Product>();

listsOfProducts.ForEach(q => q.ForEach(e => productListMerged.Add(e)));
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer from @JonSkeet is still correct but if you are using LINQ with Entity Framework (EF) then `Concat` can cause runtime errors and AddRange is not available for `IEnumerable`.

The simplest way to do this for Entity Framework would probably be a Union if you only need unique values.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=net-8.0

Using my DbContext with code like this:

```
UnresolvedThreatAndCountermeasures =
    product.ThreatAndCountermeasures.Where(tac => !tac.NotApplicable && !(tac.Verified && tac.Implemented)).Select(
        vuln => new ProductSummaryVulnerabilityDtoHelper()
        {
            AllExternalLinkIds = vuln.ExternalLinks.Select(x => x.Id).Union(vuln.Threat.ExternalLinks.Select(x => x.Id)).Union(vuln.Threat.Fork.ExternalLinks.Select(x => x.Id))
        })
```

SQL generated looks like this:

```
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t1].[Id] AS [Id0], [t2].[Id] AS [Id1], [t3].[Id] AS [Id2], [t0].[ProductId]
FROM [ThreatAndCountermeasure] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [Threats] AS [t1] ON [t0].[ThreatId] = [t1].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [Threats] AS [t2] ON [t1].[ForkId] = [t2].[Id]
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT [e].[Id]
    FROM [ExternalLink] AS [e]
    WHERE [t0].[Id] = [e].[ThreatAndCountermeasureId]
    UNION
    SELECT [e0].[Id]
    FROM [ExternalLink] AS [e0]
    WHERE [t1].[Id] = [e0].[ThreatId]
    UNION
    SELECT [e1].[Id]
    FROM [ExternalLink] AS [e1]
    WHERE ([t2].[Id] IS NOT NULL) AND [t2].[Id] = [e1].[ThreatId]
) AS [t3]
WHERE [t0].[NotApplicable] = CAST(0 AS bit) AND ([t0].[Verified] = CAST(0 AS bit) OR [t0].[Implemented] = CAST(0 AS bit))
```

You could also do it like this if you for some reason actually want duplicates:

```
public class MergedList {
  public int PrincipalId {get;set;}
  public IEnumerable<int> CombinedIds {get;set;}
}

var entitySource = _dBcontext.EntitySource.Select(e => new MergedList()
{
    PrincipalId = e.Id,
    CombinedIds = CombineLists<int>(e.table1.Select(e => e.Id), e.table2.Select(e => e.Id), e.table3.Select(e => e.Id))
}).FirstOrDefault();

private static IEnumerable<T> CombineLists<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] lists)
{
    List<T> result = new();

    foreach (var list in lists.Where(l => l != null))
    {
        result.AddRange(list);
    }

    return result;
}
```

I tested this using my DbContext like this:

```
UnresolvedThreatAndCountermeasures =
    product.ThreatAndCountermeasures.Where(tac => !tac.NotApplicable && !(tac.Verified && tac.Implemented)).Select(
        vuln => new ProductSummaryVulnerabilityDtoHelper()
        {
            AllExternalLinkIds = CombineLists<int>(vuln.ExternalLinks.Select(x => x.Id), vuln.Threat.ExternalLinks.Select(x => x.Id), vuln.Threat.Fork.ExternalLinks.Select(x => x.Id))
        })
```

and this is the query generated with expected results:

```
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t1].[Id] AS [Id0], [t3].[Id] AS [Id1], [e].[Id] AS [Id2], [e0].[Id] AS [Id3], [e1].[Id] AS [Id4], [t0].[ProductId]
FROM [ThreatAndCountermeasure] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [Threats] AS [t1] ON [t0].[ThreatId] = [t1].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [Threats] AS [t3] ON [t1].[ForkId] = [t3].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [ExternalLink] AS [e] ON [t0].[Id] = [e].[ThreatAndCountermeasureId]
LEFT JOIN [ExternalLink] AS [e0] ON [t1].[Id] = [e0].[ThreatId]
LEFT JOIN [ExternalLink] AS [e1] ON [t3].[Id] = [e1].[ThreatId]
WHERE [t0].[NotApplicable] = CAST(0 AS bit) AND ([t0].[Verified] = CAST(0 AS bit) OR [t0].[Implemented] = CAST(0 AS bit)
```

Using Concat like this:

```
var entitySource = _dBcontext.EntitySource.Select(e => new MergedList()
{
    PrincipalId = e.Id,
    CombinedIds = e.table1.Select(e => e.Id).Concat(e.table2.Select(e => e.Id)).Concat(e.table3.Select(e => e.Id))
}).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or like this:

```
CombinedValues = e.table1.Concat(e.table2).Concat(e.table3)
```

Would cause an exception like this for EF Core 7:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to translate a collection
> subquery in a projection since either parent or the subquery doesn't
> project necessary information required to uniquely identify it and
> correctly generate results on the client side. This can happen when
> trying to correlate on keyless entity type. This can also happen for
> some cases of projection before 'Distinct' or some shapes of grouping
> key in case of 'GroupBy'. These should either contain all key
> properties of the entity that the operation is applied on, or only
> contain simple property access expressions.'

Even if you try to project the list chances are quite high you would end up with something like this for `Concat`:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'MaterializeCollectionNavigation(
    Navigation: MyObject.MyList,
    subquery: DbSet<MyListObject>()
        .Where(e => EF.Property<int?>(t.Outer.Outer, "Id") != null && object.Equals(
            objA: (object)EF.Property<int?>(t.Outer.Outer, "Id"), 
            objB: (object)EF.Property<int?>(e, "MyObjectId")))
        .Where(i => EF.Property<int?>(t.Outer.Outer, "Id") != null && object.Equals(
            objA: (object)EF.Property<int?>(t.Outer.Outer, "Id"), 
            objB: (object)EF.Property<int?>(i, "MyObjectId"))))
    .AsQueryable()
    .Concat(MaterializeCollectionNavigation(
        Navigation: MyObject2.MyList,
        subquery: DbSet<MyListObject>()
            .Where(e0 => EF.Property<int?>(t.Outer.Inner, "Id") != null && object.Equals(
                objA: (object)EF.Property<int?>(t.Outer.Inner, "Id"), 
                objB: (object)EF.Property<int?>(e0, "MyObject2Id")))
            .Where(i => EF.Property<int?>(t.Outer.Inner, "Id") != null && object.Equals(
                objA: (object)EF.Property<int?>(t.Outer.Inner, "Id"), 
                objB: (object)EF.Property<int?>(i, "MyObject2Id")))))
    .Concat(t.Outer.Inner.ForkId != null ? MaterializeCollectionNavigation(
        Navigation: MyObject2.MyList,
        subquery: DbSet<MyListObject>()
            .Where(e1 => EF.Property<int?>(t.Inner, "Id") != null && object.Equals(
                objA: (object)EF.Property<int?>(t.Inner, "Id"), 
                objB: (object)EF.Property<int?>(e1, "MyObject2Id")))
            .Where(i => EF.Property<int?>(t.Inner, "Id") != null && object.Equals(
                objA: (object)EF.Property<int?>(t.Inner, "Id"), 
                objB: (object)EF.Property<int?>(i, "MyObject2Id")))) : new List<MyListObject>())' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'
```

See this post for more info:

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26703#issuecomment-981843751

Original post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76046347/3850405