# How to concatenate ReadOnlyCollection<string> and IList<string>

Tags: c#, list, concatenation

I have two property for `readonlucollection` and IList
and created another property of `List<string>`
`OptionList` is `readonlycollection<string>` and `ForList` is `IList<string>`
But I don't get full list in combine list it skipped some elements from `optionlist`.

How do i get full list?

```
public List<string> CombineList {
    get {
        return OptionList.Union(ForList).ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Union` method skips elements common to both lists. If you would like to have a list that keeps duplicates, use concatenation instead of union:

```
return OptionList.Concat(ForList).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Concat` if you want to concatenate. `Union` has an implicit distinct built-in.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be `Union`and that you dont use `Concat`. There is a slight diference which is described in the post below: (hope this helpes :) )

In this post: [Union Vs Concat in Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13417556/union-vs-concat-in-linq)

i would recomend this approach:

```
OptionList.Concat(forList).ToList();
```