# unique LINQ to filter list by variables (case insensitive)

Tags: c#, list, linq, filter, case-insensitive

I have

```
public int practice_example6 (List<Car> cars)
```

I want to filter this list by `Make` that contains the word `"Toyota"` but not for that filter to be case sensitive. My other conditions are that `SuggestedRetailPrice` should be less than 30000.

I think I'm almost there but am confused about how to handle the case insensitive issue.

```
if (cars == null)
{
   return 0;
}
else
{
   List<Car> filtered = cars.Where(x => x.Make == "honda").ToList();
   List<Car> filtered2 = cars.Where(x => x.Make == "Honda").ToList();
   List<Car> filtered3 = cars.Where(x => x.SuggestedRetailPrice < 30000).ToList();
}
```

I'm also not sure on how to return 3 variables (filtered1,2,3) in one return statement. Perhaps just combine those 3 into one variable and then return that?

I'm a beginner and have researched about this. I would appreciate explanations not just fixes.

Thanks!

EDIT: I should not I have to do this without changing the function to IEnumerable practice_example6(List cars) - I know this would be ideal but there are constraints imposed.

Comment: Seeing the last stipulation, I think they want you to use `FindAll`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
string.Equals(x.Make, "Honda", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

so something like:

```
List<Car> filtered = cars.Where(x => string.Equals(x.Make, "Honda", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList();
```

Full method:

```
if (cars == null)
{
   return 0;
}
else
{
   return cars.Count(x => string.Equals(x.Make, "Honda", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && x.SuggestedRetailPrice < 30000);
}
```

Comment: This does not work because I can't return "filtered" because it has to be in List<> form.

Comment: Not sure that I understand.. Do you need to return how many of the Car elements satisfy the filter criteria?

Comment: Yes. It won't let me return "filtered" because as written above, your code is trying to return an int. I want to ultimately return a list of cars named "Honda"(case insensitive) that are priced less than 30,000

Comment: Thanks for the edits, I must be missing something. The edited code doesn't work because I can't use "ToList();" because the type int doesn't have a definition for "ToList".

Comment: sorry my bad, I didnt remove ToList(). try now

Comment: That worked! Thank you! If you wouldn't mind, could your reasoning behind your method?

Comment: sure I used the Count(expression) extension method on the list, to simply count the number of items that satisfy the expression.
For the expression itself I used the string.Equals() as culture insensitive and combined multiple criteria with logical AND - &&

Answer (score 4):

Use an insensitive `IndexOf`:

```
return cars.Where(x => x.Make.IndexOf("honda", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1 ||
                       x.SuggestedRetailPrice < 3000)
           .ToList();
```

*Notice that ignoring case also means that input as "honDa"/ "hONDA"/ "HONDA" and such will also be accepted*

---

Also, your functions is `public int practice_example6 (List<Car> cars)` which returns an int. You cannot return the filtered list that way. Change the function to return `IEnumerable<Car>` or `Count`, depending on what you need:

```
public int practice_example6(List<Car> cars)
{
    return cars == null ? 0 :
        cars.Count(x => x.Make.IndexOf("honda", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1 ||
                        x.SuggestedRetailPrice < 3000);
}
```

---

As for the general case of concatenating 3 collections use `Concat` or `Union` depending on case: *([Union Vs Concat in Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13417556/union-vs-concat-in-linq))*

```
filtered.Concat(filtered2).Concat(filtered3);
```

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. Unfortunately I have to use the function as it is written (this is for an online course I am using). So I can not change the function.

Comment: @William - only saw now that what you wanted is the count so in any case updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about this ?

```
   List<Car> filtered = cars.Where(x => x.Make.ToLower() == "honda").ToList();
```