# Dynamic Linq using Or

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following dynamic linq

```
var results=(from a in alist where a.id==id select a)
if(...something)
{
results=(from a in results where a.amount>input1 && a.typeId==1 select a)
}
if(...something else)
{
results=(from a in results where a.amount>input2 && a.typeId==2 select a)
}
if(...something else again)
{
results=(from a in results where a.amount>input3 && a.typeId==3 select a)
}
```

However this produces an AND statement which means all the statements need to be true for anything to be returned.

I need the last 3 statements to be ORed together.

eg I want

> Where (a.id==id) && ((a.amount>input1 && a.typeId==1) ||
>   (a.amount>input2 && a.typeId==2) || (a.amount>input3 && a.typeId==3))

How do I do this?

Comment: Can't you change the AND statements `&&` for OR statements `||`? Is that what you're looking?

Comment: I think you made an error, for it to become an `AND` you need to write `results=(from a in results ...)`

Comment: @peter b. You are correct. I have made the change. Trigger happy cut and paste was to blame :-)

Comment: @Ikerbera. It is not those that I want to OR. It is each if the groups. For example I want results where (a.amount>input1 && a.typeId==1) || (a.amount>input2 && a.typeId==2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use .Concat()

I am not absolutely sure if I understood you question correctly, but this code will create a resultset that is **appended to** if your if conditions are true, **rather than replacing** the original resultset.

```
var results=(from a in alist where a.id==id select a)
if(...something)
{
    results = results.Concat((from a in alist where a.amount>input1 && a.typeId==1 select a))
}
if(...something else)
{
    results = results.Concat((from a in alist where a.amount>input2 && a.typeId==2 select a))
}
//....
```

Edited as per Peter B's comment.

**If multiple lists may contain the same element** and you only wish to have every element at most once, use `.Union` instead of `.Concat`. This has some performance penalty of course (having to compare the elements).

## After your edit

Your edit clarified things a bit. You have two options:

1. Move your `a.id == id` check into the inner queries:

   ```
   var results=Enumerable.Empty<typeofa>()
   if(...something)
   {
       results = results.Concat((from a in alist where a.id == id && a.amount>input1 && a.typeId==1 select a))
   }
   if(...something else)
   {
       results = results.Concat((from a in alist where a.id == id && a.amount>input2 && a.typeId==2 select a))
   }
   //....
   ```
2. First filter the set using the id, materialize that, then further narrow that down using the method I showed above.

   ```
   var results=Enumerable.Empty<typeofa>();
   var fileterdList = (from a in alist where a.id==id select a).ToList();
   if(...something)
   {
       results = results.Concat((from a in fileterdList where a.amount>input1 && a.typeId==1 select a))
   }
   if(...something else)
   {
       results = results.Concat((from a in fileterdList where a.amount>input2 && a.typeId==2 select a))
   }
   //....
   ```

   Whichever works better depends on your situation. General advice is that prefiltering is more efficient if it narrows down the list considerably and/or the original source is relatively expensive to query (sql for example), but as always, you should profile your concrete example yourself.

Comment: This may produce duplicate entries. See [Union Vs Concat in Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13417556/1220550)

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in my initial question. I am already appending the results but this is on an AND basis rather than an OR, so my result set returns no results.

Comment: This is how my code in this answer works. Assuming both if conditions are true you will get results where `a.id == id` OR `a.amount>input1` && `a.typeId==1 OR a.amount>input2 && a.typeId==2`.

Comment: Using a predicate builder is much better. This code executes one query for each OR condition and it contains a lot of repetitive code.

Answer (score 4):

Check the [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) class. This is a famous implementation of extensions methods for `Linq` to easily perform dynamic logic operations with `OR` and `AND`.

Given your list is of a `TypeA` for sample, you coul try this:

```
Expression<Func<TypeA, bool>> filter = a => a.id == id;

if(...something)
{
   filter = filter.Or(a => a...);
}

if(...something)
{
   filter = filter.Or(a => a...);
}

if(...something)
{
   filter = filter.Or(a => a...);
}


var results = alist.Where(filter).ToList();
```