# Easiest way to merge a changed list to the master list

Tags: c#, winforms, list

I have a two lists of class object :

```
private List<IntVector> UserData = new List<IntVector>();
private List<IntVector> EditData = new List<IntVector>();
```

`UserData` is the Master List and `EditData` is another list which would be used to add, delete, or modify the list. One of the class memeber is `CaseNo` which would not change for an IntVector.

I have made changes in the `EditData` and would like to merge the changes to the `UserData`.

Any idea how to do it ?

EDIT :  Here is the definition of `IntVector`

```
class IntVector
    {
        //private DateTime date_kept;
        private string date1;
        private string next_date;
        private string presence;
        private string next_hearing_time;


        //private Hashtable case_type;
        private string court_name;
        private string case_no;
        private string status;
.
.
.
        public string Date1
        {
            set { this.date1 = value; }
            get { return this.date1; }
        }

        public string NextDate
        {
            get { return this.next_date; }
            set { this.next_date = value; }
        }

}
```

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488054/merge-two-or-more-lists-into-one-in-c-sharp-net

Comment: Can you show us IntVector body?

Comment: It is not clear why you need the separate lists.  Why not just edit UserData or make EditData only have the entries which were edited?

Comment: Well, UserData is not modified Only Changes are committed to it. The changes ( both addition, deletion, modification) would reflect in EditData

Comment: @KiranChandrashekhar if the difference between `addition, deletion and modification` is important then I'm afraid you need more than just a simple `Concatenation`, for each item you shoud check to see if it is in `addition` state to be added or ...

Comment: The statement "Well, UserData is not modified Only Changes are committed to it." does not make sense to me, are you saying that `UserData` is the complete list and `EditData` is the list of changes which need to be made to `UserData`?  In that case for each item in `EditData` you would need to find the matching value in `UserData` and replace it right?

Comment: No, EditData would not contain just the changes. To give an analogy, you have a source file in cvs and make the changes and you need to checkin that change. How would you do it. Instead of source file, I have a list of class object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `IntVector` is a struct, the `IList.Union` method does what you need by merging a list and removing duplicates:

```
UserData  = UserData.Union(EditData).ToList();
```

If it is not a struct.. then you can still do the above, however you'll have to overload the equality operator, `Equals` and possibly `GetHashCode` for it.

Comment: So, if ther are changes in EditData, how would Union work ? Which object is selected. If there are changes, they will not be duplicates right ? For union() they are 2 different objects

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something like:

```
UserData = (from u in UserData
                      join e in EditData
                      on u.CaseNo equals e.CaseNo
                      into joined
                      from x in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      select new IntVector
                      {
                          CaseNo = u.CaseNo,
                          Data = x == null ? u.Data : x.Data
                      }).ToList();
```