# Merge two List<object> into one List in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have two lists. `BeamElevations<Elevation>` and `FloorElevations<Elevation>`. How can I merge these into `Elevations<Elevation>` list and order them based on their Elevation using Linq?

Comment: Didnt down vote but id imagine its because of the lack of research effort

Comment: i think it's because people are nobs

Comment: @Sayse Actually I searched SO before posting this. But I found the answer after posting the question. I thought it doesn't hurt for this to remain on the website. It will definitely help some lost guy some day in the future.

Comment: First google result...    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488054/merge-two-or-more-lists-into-one-in-c-sharp-net

Comment: @Sayse Thanks. I didn't see that.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use [`Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var result = list1.Concat(list2).OrderBy(x => x.Elevation).ToList();
```

If you want to remove duplicates and get an unique set of elements you can also use [`Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
var result = list1.Union(list2).OrderBy(x => x.Elevation).ToList();
```

In order to make it work properly you need to overide `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods in your class.

Comment: @Vahid yes you can but it will remove the duplicates if you override equals and gethascode for your class.It is different from Concat see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731(v=vs.110).aspx) : _This method excludes duplicates from the return set._

Comment: I see. I'll stick with `Union` then.

Comment: Some people have lots of free time on their hands :)

Comment: I don't know, It seems somebody think that I see the Union in the other answer and added after that but I didn't even noticed it mentioned in another answer I include it because Vahid ask me in the comments

Comment: @Vahid I don't know, you should try it and see.I would say Concat is faster because it justs merging the items without comparing them.Union performs much more work than Concat

Comment: Thanks I guess it is.

Comment: Why to use orderBy ?

Answer (score 6):

Initially you merge them like below:

```
Elevations=BeamElevations.Union(FloorElevations)
    .ToList();
```

Then

```
Elevations=Elevations.OrderBy(x=>x.Elevation)
    .ToList();
```

Or in one step:

```
Elevations=BeamElevations.Union(FloorElevations)
    .OrderBy(x=>x.Elevation)
    .ToList();
```

Another way to achieve this would be to use `Concat`

```
Elevations=BeamElevations.Concat(FloorElevations)
    .OrderBy(x=>x.Elevation)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer.

Comment: this is not complete, Union will not remove anything if you don't override the equals and gethashcode.It will work just like the Concat

Comment: @Selman22 I just updated my answer in order to be correct, thank you agian.

Answer (score 3):

Use [List.AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
   list1.AddRange(list2);
   list1.OrderBy(l => l.Elevation);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 List<Elevation> Elevations= FloorElevations.Concat(BeamElevations).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

If there are any devs out there that might be looking for a solution in VB.NET, here you go:

```
Dim list1 As List(Of MyObject)
Dim list2 As List(Of MyObject)
Dim mergedAndSortedList As List(Of MyObject)

mergedAndSortedList = (From obj In list1.Union(list2)
                       Order By obj.MyPropertyToSortOn
                       Select obj).ToList()
```