# How to merge two ILists together

Tags: c#, .net, ilist

I have two ILists in my which are getting values from the separate tables within the database. These tables contain the same columns and values but for other reasons the client needs them stored in separate tables.

```
private IList<MeterReadingDto> _meterReadings;
private IList<PseudoReadingDto>  _pseudoReading;
public IList<MeterReadingDto> MeterReadings
    {
        get
        {
            return _meterReadings != null ? _meterReadings.OrderByDescending(x => x.ReadDate).ToList() : null;
        }
        set { _meterReadings = value; }
    }

    public IList<PseudoReadingDto> PseudoReadings
    {
        get
        {
            return _pseudoReading != null ? _pseudoReading.OrderByDescending(x => x.ReadDate).ToList() : null;
        }
        set { _pseudoReading = value; }
    }
```

As you can see they both get the results and store them, but i now need to merge/union these list so that they can be displayed in one table. Any ideas on how to do this

Comment: So why do you use two different classes for the same data structure from two tables?

Comment: Note that if they have the same columns, you will want them to implement a common interface to simplify merging with Concat, or have them share a common base class.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you can extract an interface (or ever a base class) for `MeterReadingDto` and `PseudoReadingDto`, than you could merge them to a `IEnumerable` or `IList` of that.

i.e.

```
public IEnumerable<BaseReadingDto> AllReadings {
  get{
    return MeterReadings.Concat(PseudoReadings);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the IEnumerable method extension [Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358407(v=vs.100).aspx).

NOTE: Using this operation will result in duplicate elements between the two collections being removed from the result.

Comment: Union will discard any elements that the two IList have in common.

Comment: Oh, okay. I saw this note: The Concat<TSource> method differs from the Union method because the Concat<TSource> method returns all the elements in the input sequences including duplicates, whereas Union returns only unique values. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to treat both `PseudoReadingDto` and `MeterReadingDto` as the same object type.  You could look into anonymous types, but I suggest having both implement the same interface (like maybe `IReadingDto`).  Then you can create a new `List<IReadingDto>` and combine the lists.

If they share the same type, you can use `List.AddRange()` to append the lists together.

Comment: Using AddRange is especially efficient compared to Concat if you know the size of the final list ahead of time http://stackoverflow.com/a/4488073/141172.