# Populate listView control with items from a List<ListViewItem>

Tags: c#, winforms, list, listview, listviewitem

I have **four** `List<ListViewItem>` and **one** `listView control`.

What I want is to populate the control with the items from the lists.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is first merge the four lists into one and then add them to the ListView's Items collection.

```
var allListItems = list1.Concat(list2)
                        .Concat(list3)
                        .Concat(list4)
                        .ToList();

listView.Items.AddRange(allListItems);
```

This is not very pretty or the best performing solution but it does the job. Take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488054/merge-two-or-more-lists-into-one-in-c-sharp-net) to get a better idea on how to merge more than one list to one.