# C# How to combine 2 list in different row count then implement in Form of DataGridView Controller?

Tags: c#

I have 2 list list1, list2,

```
class classList
{   
    public string p1{ get; set; }
    public string p2 { get; set; }
    public string p3 { get; set; }
    public string p4 { get; set; }
}

List<classList> list1= new List<classList>();
List<classList> list2= new List<classList>();


        p1  p2  p3  p4
list1 =  1   2   3   4
         5   6   7   8

        p1   p2   p3   p4
list2 = 10   12   13   14
        15   16   17   18
        19   20   21   22
```

now I would like joint 2 list to datagridview just like this

[image]

How can I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: Its easy. http://automapper.org/ or check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488054/merge-two-or-more-lists-into-one-in-c-sharp-net

Comment: show what you have tried? and by datafridview what do you mean? a .NET Forms datagrid? (is it a program, app, web?)

Comment: Sorry! My question is I would like to add List2 to new column not to next rows. I think Concat is wrong ! thanks!

Comment: the problem is that it is not really possible to keep the "header" value as one row only can contain one columb with p1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a type that can hold a combined data item for a full row. For example:

```
class CombinedItem
{
    public string p1 { get; set; }
    public string p2 { get; set; }
    public string p3 { get; set; }
    public string p4 { get; set; }

    public string q1 { get; set; }
    public string q2 { get; set; }
    public string q3 { get; set; }
    public string q4 { get; set; }
}
```

Then merge your source lists. I use `Enumerable.Repeat` and `Concat` to bring the lists to same size and then `Zip` and the null-conditional operator to create the result:

```
List<classList> list1 = new List<classList>();
List<classList> list2 = new List<classList>();

IEnumerable<classList> enumerable1 = list1;
IEnumerable<classList> enumerable2 = list2;
if (list1.Count < list2.Count)
{
    enumerable1 = enumerable1.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(default(classList), list2.Count - list1.Count));
}
else if (list2.Count < list1.Count)
{
    enumerable2 = enumerable2.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(default(classList), list1.Count - list2.Count));
}
var resultItems = enumerable1.Zip(enumerable2, (e1, e2) => new CombinedItem
    {
        p1 = e1?.p1,
        p2 = e1?.p2,
        p3 = e1?.p3,
        p4 = e1?.p4,
        q1 = e2?.p1,
        q2 = e2?.p2,
        q3 = e2?.p3,
        q4 = e2?.p4,
    }).ToList();
```

**Edit:**

You can try `DisplayNameAttribute` in order to make the `q1, q2, q3, q4` columns appear as `p1, p2, p3, p4` like:

```
[DisplayName("p1")]
public string q1 { get; set; }
```

But you have to test if your DataGridView is actually using this attribute and whether duplicate display names are accepted.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to do it by hand. You need to specify the number of columns in advance:

```
dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 8;
```

Then iterate with a loop through each list and assign the values:

```
void fillDataGrid()    
{
    list1.Add(new classList { p1 = "1", p2 = "2", p3 = "3", p4 = "4" });
    list1.Add(new classList { p1 = "5", p2 = "6", p3 = "7", p4 = "8" });

    list2.Add(new classList { p1 = "9", p2 = "10", p3 = "11", p4 = "12" });
    list2.Add(new classList { p1 = "13", p2 = "14", p3 = "15", p4 = "16" });

    dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 8;

    for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
    {
        this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = list1[i].p1;
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = list1[i].p2;
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = list1[i].p3;
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = list1[i].p4;            
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < list2.Count; i++)
    {
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = list2[i].p1;
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = list2[i].p2;
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value = list2[i].p3;
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value = list2[i].p4;
    }
}
```

The resulting `DataGridView` will look like this:

[image]

EDIT: if you want the headers you can specify them like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText = "p" + ((i % 4)+1);
}
```

or you can use `System.Reflection` to get the real names of your properties if you like:

```
int propCount = 0;
string [] propnames = typeof(classList).GetProperties().Select(x=>x.Name).ToArray();
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText = propnames[propCount];
    propCount = i % propnames.Length;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution!

Comment: @sarah You are welcome. The best way to thank on StackOverflow is to [mark the answer that helped you as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Good day :)