# C# Linq merge multiple lists?

Tags: c#, linq

```
var results = from thing in AnArrayOfThings
              let list = Function(thing)
              ???
              select OneLongResultsList;
```

How can I merge all the "list" collections into one long list?
I'm new to linq and I can't use lambda expressions.

Basically, what I want to do, is this:

```
List<Result> results = new ...;
foreach (Thing t in ListOfThings)
{
    List<Result> list = Function( t );
    results.MergeOrAdd( list );
}
```

Comment: Is two list are same type? Try some tutorials. Concat , Union are some of methods. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720609/create-a-list-from-two-object-lists-with-linq

Comment: [Merge two (or more) lists into one, in C# .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4488061/1417185)

Comment: Yes, they are the same type. Concat works with two lists, which I don't know how to adapt to multiple, like in a foreach loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you just need `SelectMany`?

```
var results = AnArrayOfThings.SelectMany(x => Function(x));
```

Or in query syntax:

```
var results = from thing in AnArrayOfThings
              from thingInAList in Function(thing)
              select thingInAList;
```

Comment: ooh so this gets all the "thingInAList" ...things of all the lists??

Comment: @Herpn'nFoDerp yes it's like a flatMap function.