# How to combine a two variable to a single variable in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

**Model**

```
 public partial class IndustryLandingHeader :EntityModel
 {
 [TextField]
    public virtual string Headline { get; set; }
    [TextField]
    public virtual string Type { get; set; }
    [KeywordField]
    public virtual KeyWordMetaSchema ParentIndustry { get; set; }
    [KeywordField]
    public virtual List<KeyWordMetaSchema> SubIndustries { get; set; }
    [TextField]
    public virtual string LabelForSubIndustry { get; set; }
    [KeywordTitleField]
    public virtual List<KeyWordMetaSchema> AdditionalKeyword { get; set; }
 }
```

need to combine SUBINDUSTRIES and ADDITIONALKEYWORD variable alone as single variable
Here I have two different variable name needs  to be combined to single variable .How to do that?

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488054/merge-two-or-more-lists-into-one-in-c-sharp-net

Comment: nope. i need to combine subindustries and additionkeyword to single variable name @Iren Saltali

Comment: can you put example of how do you need it?

Comment: Do you want both List into single List ?

Comment: yes both List into single List   @shaijut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use the LINQ Concat and ToList methods

```
var allProducts = productCollection1.Concat(productCollection2)
                                .Concat(productCollection3)
                                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new collection and add there:

```
...
var combineList = new List<KeyWordMetaSchema>();

combineList.AddRange(industryLandingHeades.SubIndustries);
combineList.AddRange(industryLandingHeades.AdditionalKeyword);
```

Comment: If you are going to do it this way (which I am not suggesting, but if you are) you may as well pass the expected size (i.e. capacity) to the `List` constructor (since you know what it is).

Answer (score 0):

As you are looking Both List into single List.

Just call the main `Class` or `VM`:

```
//TODO: Populate the data in List.

var singleList = new List<IndustryLandingHeader>();
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try the below :

```
this.SubIndustries.Concat(this.AdditionalKeyword).ToList()
```

[List.Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=netframework-4.8) method creates a new sequence of items from both lists without affecting the original list.

**Note** that Concat method returns IEnumerable<> collection and so we need to apply ToList() over the output of concat method

Comment: Please add a link to your details, this way an user can always double check the terms and read more about a new command. [List.Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Here is the link...https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=netframework-4.8    In general any collection implementing IEnumerable supports concat method